# Is it possible to use pages to apply static content to each taxonomy level?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, pages

I'm thinking of using a taxonomy archive template to list out my taxonomies and entries (I'm using a hierarchical structure) and then combining this with the WordPress pages module to apply static content to each taxonomy level.

Each level will essentially have its own page and will list either its children or entries (posts). The idea I had was to create a page with the same slug as my taxonomy and then assign the taxonomy archive template to this page.

Just wondered if anyone had done this before, or if its even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : Yes its posible!

long answer: Not the best way to do waht you are trying to do, when i need static content to go along with taxonomy terms i use the terms description field and in case that i need even more i just add my extra custom fields to the taxonomy term, here is a nice tutorial [**add extra fields to WordPress Custom taxonomies**](http://en.bainternet.info/2011/custom-taxonomies-extra-fields).

this way the creation of the terms archive beacomes much more dynamic.

Comment: Wow, this looks perfect my only reason for using the pages module was because it had the wysiwyg, I'm sure theres a way to implement this into one of the fields on this page?

Comment: you can do that with this class http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/taxonomy-meta-script-for-wordpress.html

Comment: Do you think it is safe to use the deluxeblogtips class? In reading through the comments it appears that there 'may' be some pretty serious errors. 'Not good enough coder yet to troubleshoot the class on my own'